# Play framework merge POST with model

Tags: java, database, merge, playframework-2.0, save

I am trying to learn the Play framework however i hit a roadblock and the documentation did not cover my issue (google resulted in nothing). What i am trying to do is making a multi page form that updates every time to the database.

Lets say the form is made in 5 steps and they cant be on the same page. What i've got working is that the first page works like intended (this also has the required data, the rest is optional)

> ERROR executing DML bindLog[] error[Invalid value "null" for parameter "SQL"

After some searching i found that this had to do with the fact that the second page does not have the required data and thus sets those values to null. Meaning when i want to save the object it cant because all the other values are null.

Now my current saving code is pretty straightforward:

```
User userUpdate = Form.form(User.class).bindFromRequest().get();
userUpdate.update(id);
```

(the id value is from the action)

i've also tried the following:

```
User userUpdate = Form.form(User.class).fill(User.find.byId(id)).bindFromRequest().get();
userUpdate.update(id);
```

And in both cases my program crashes because of the null values.

So what i need is a push in the right direction to merge the current model with the form data so that i can save it. If someone has an good example on how to do it that would be really helpful!

P.s. this is my current model:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model{

    @Id
    public Long id;

    public String username;
    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;


    public static Finder<Long,User> find = new Finder<Long,User>(Long.class, User.class);

    public Form getUserFormByID(Long id){
        Form<User> userForm = Form.form(User.class);

        if(id > 0){
            userForm = userForm.fill(
                    this.find.byId(id)
            );
        }
        return userForm;
    }
}
```